# Finish Feature with GIT Flow failed first time worked second?

Tags: git, version-control, git-flow, atlassian-sourcetree

I am using [SourceTree](http://sourcetreeapp.com/) with a BitBucket repository and have been using GIT Flow. I have been working on my first feature branch and have decided to use the "Finish Feature" option to merge it into the develop branch.

The first time I selected this option I got an error message complaining that there were conflicts. The feature branch had been deleted and there were a number of files with changes that had not been committed. I cannot understand why there would be any conflicts in this particular scenario; or even how such conflicts would be resolved in this seemingly (from my confused eyes) corrupt state.

So to avoid damage I deleted my local branches and checked them out from origin. I re-activated the feature branch and attempted the "Finish Feature" option again. This time it worked without any errors.

What factors can lead to this problem?

Comment: Uncommitted changes in working directory, perhaps?

Comment: @user1615903 Not in this scenario, I committed and pushed all changes to origin before attempting the "Finish Feature" since this was my first time and didn't want to break anything.

Comment: @user1615903 Just to clarify, when you say working directory, do you mean the *now* (well at the stage of confusion) working directory "develop" or the *prior* working directory "feature/my-new-feature"?

Comment: The current working directory, one you had checked out when you did the finish feature. I suspected this because doing a checkout from the origin fixed the issue.